# Scaling invariance for Hartree equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider [generalized  Hartree Equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05339)

$  i \partial_t u + \Delta u + \left( \frac{1}{|x|^{\gamma}} \ast |u|^p \right)|u|^{p-2}u, \quad u(x, 0)=u_0(x)$
where $0<\gamma<d, p\geq 2,  u(x,t)\in \mathbb C.$

When $p=2$ $-$ classical Hartree equation.

Scaling invariance: if $u(t,x)$ solves  GHE, then so does
$ u_{\lambda}(t,x)= \lambda^{\frac{d-\gamma +2}{2(p-1)}} u (\lambda^2 t, \lambda x)$
also.

> My question is: What is the scaling invariance  for fractional generalized  Hartree equation:
> $  i \partial_t u - (- \Delta)^{\alpha/2} u + \left( \frac{1}{|x|^{\gamma}} \ast |u|^p \right)|u|^{p-2}u, \quad u(x, 0)=u_0(x)$

Comment: Carlo already answered your question: but this is essentially just a plug-and-chug question. The linear terms determine the scaling relation between $t$ and $x$. And after that you just solve an algebraic equation for the scaling factor in front of the function. // Are you asking the question because you don't know how to do this computation (in which case Carlo's answer is unlikely to be too helpful), or because you cannot be bothered to do it yourself?

Answer (score 5):

substitution of $u_\mu(t,x)=\text{constant}\times u(\mu^\alpha t,\mu x)$ in the fractional GHE shows that this is a solution if $\text{constant}=\mu^{\frac{d-\gamma+\alpha}{2(p-1)}}$, so the scale invariance relation is
$$u_\mu(t,x)=\mu^{\frac{d-\gamma+\alpha}{2(p-1)}}u(\mu^\alpha t,\mu x).$$